How do you remove a python venv from vscode?
I've added several custom virtual environments to vscode, so that when I use the command palette I can select from a variety of builtin ones, as well as my own.
I'd like to remove some of these, but I can't figure out where vscode stores these.  I don't have a settings.json in my workspace, but it still remembers the ones I've added via a custom interpreter path.  I'd also like to remove some of the builtin ones like ~/anaconda3/python.exe, and ~/anaconda3/envs/sd_playground/python.exe, which I never added and am never going to use.
What json or other settings file can I edit to make vscode not know about these?

This wiki page for the vscode-Python extension on GitHub explains how the extension finds installed interpreters and environments. There are different locators for each environment type.  Unfortunately it doesn't provide the best info on how to hide/delete environments from those locators and the cache.

Some additional info here in the vscode documentation

Remove the extra venv path from setings.json and manually delete venv folder for any auto-detected but unwanted environments.

Remove the extra venv path from python.venvPath in vscode setting.
